# Amplify federated saml sign in not authenticated

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So I'm not quite understanding why this isn't working. Some background; We have a SAML identity provider in our user pool, its a registered identity in our identity pool as well which i see when i go to dashboard. I am pretty frustrated form the lack of central documentation for Amplify, it's incredibly difficult to find anything online and I just keep trying things I see and they don't work.

What I already have:

I already have it working in the sense that I get an access_token back from the SAML provider, and that all works fine. So I know it's working fine (the login part), but the issue I am having is basically updating Amplify to now have the user in session so we can take advantage of functionality within Amplify that lets you refresh tokens when they expire.

Essentially, this is the flow I am using, from different sources I've found online:

`await Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider });`

this line of code can either be `google`, `facebook` or our custom SAML one we made. I already know this works, bc again, I already get my access token. So now, this is where my confusion starts. Obviously this function call here will take the user away from the page, hence we cant `await` this call, or i mean, you can, but it wont return the user on page reload. Which is fine, that part makes sense. So I have a function when the component is loaded that checks to see if theres a `access_token` in the url hash, which works as well.

Now, the issue is, Amplify doesn't know we signed in. We have "logged in" in the sense that yes, we have a valid JWT token now from the url hash `access_token` but the local Amplify does not know that this user is logged in.

So this is what I am talking about with the lack of documentation, perhaps I am crazy but I can't find a central source for how to handle this anywhere. I figured, once we have an `id_token` perhaps we can take advantage of Amplify Auth's `federatedSignIn` but now instead of just passing in a provider, they do have an option to send in a provider name, an id token, and expiree time and a user object, as noted [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#federatedsignin)

As you can see there's different ways you can use this function, so I figure now that I have the id_token back from the response, I can use this method to actually tell Amplify that yes I am indeed logged in. As such:

```js
    await Auth.federatedSignIn(
      provider_name,
      {
        token: id_token,
        expires_at: expires_in,
      },
      user
    )
```

When this fires I get the following error:

`issue with access token NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName`

Now I have verified 100% that the providerName is correct. This is the SAME provider name we pass in the original `federatedSignIn` call. the id_token is also the jwt id_token we get back from the Cognito and the SSO provider. the expiree is also `3600` so im assuming thats valid, and if it wasnt, the error would be different. I am just lost as to what I need to do at this point.

How can I have amplify recognize a federated sign in user? Since all we get back is a access_token and im beginning to think im not using the `federatedSignIn` method properly.

Comment: Also I am not interested in using the Cognito Hosted UI.

Comment: did you figure out how it works?

Comment: @Lerman yeah sorry never updated this, but i believe if i recall correctly, i figured out the JWT I had was from the wrong environment. We have dev, qa..etc and i wasn't getting the right JWT from the environment it was validating with. Hope this helps, if not i would make sure the provider name you're passing matches what's in cognito under your federated identities. i might be able to help you debug if theres such a way to do that, im sure its a simple fix, this was just bc jwt was from a different environment.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually didn’t try to use the federatedSignIn function again with the token.
I got the token in the url but also got console errors of ‘not authenticated’ and ‘Username cannot be empty’. In every video I saw, after calling federatedSignIn(provider) they managed to get the user details with the currentAuthenticatedUser function, but I get ‘not authenticated’, So I figured I’m doing something wrong.

Comment: Is calling  federatedSignIn again with the token is actually the right flow? after calling  federatedSignIn(provider) all the lambda triggers are executed - meaning tokens have already been generated.,,
real crappy documentation!

Comment: from the documentation i saw yes, this was the correct flow. if you find anything that points to the contrary let me know.